# Matplotlib: How to mirror an image with respect to both axes?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, networkx, mirroring

I am working with `NetworkX` in order to evaluate the dynamics that occur in a network. Then I visually represent the result. I work with the following:

```
#Step 1: Creating the original network
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplotas plt
N=100
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N) #2D regular graph of 10000 nodes
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dict of positions
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
pos = {y:x for x,y in labels.iteritems()} #Renamed positions. Position (0,0) is in the upper left corner now.
H=G.copy()

#Step 2: Dynamics modeling block

#Step 3: Plotting the resulting network
G2=dict((k, v) for k, v in status_nodes_model.items() if v < 1) #All nodes that must be removed from the regular grid
H.remove_nodes_from(G2)
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos=pos, with_labels=False, node_size = 10)
        plt.xlim(-20,120,10)
        plt.xticks(numpy.arange(-20, 130, 20.0))
        plt.ylim(-20,120,10) 
        plt.yticks(numpy.arange(-20, 130, 20.0))
        plt.axis('on')
        plt.plot((0, 100), (0, 0), '0.60') #Line1 - visual boundary for failure stages
        plt.plot((0, 0), (0, 100), '0.60') #Line2 - visual boundary for failure stages
        plt.plot((0, 100), (100, 100), '0.60') #Line3 - visual boundary for failure stages
        plt.plot((100, 100), (0, 100), '0.60') #Line4 - visual boundary for failure stages
        title_string=('Lattice Network, Stage 2') 
        subtitle_string=('Impact & dynamics | Active nodes: '+str(act_nodes_model)+' | Failed nodes: '+str(failed_nodes_haz+failed_nodes_model)+' | Total failure percentage: '+str(numpy.around(100*(failed_nodes_haz+failed_nodes_model)/10000,2))+'%')
        plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
        plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)
```

What I visually get is an UNWANTED MIRRORING. Please see below:
[image]

**My question:** is there a way of mirroring the output image **both horizontally and vertically**, so that the image to the right is obtained, but with readable titles and labels?

Comment: I think you will have to mirror the axes too. Have you though that in the right example above, you have points in x = 0 and y = 0 that you don't have in left example. Mirroring axes would be quite easy I think. Don't mirror the axes it's a differente chart I think

Comment: Yep, what I would really like to do is transform my image by mirroring the axes. This is not something that I want to change graphically, after the wrong image is produced (e.g., with Photoshop), but numerically, BEFORE it is produced.

Comment: and have you tried reversing the axes lists?

Comment: You could try generate the arange from the positive to the negative value. This way you will reverse the axe

Comment: Probably that it's not clear what effort you made to solve the problem before posting your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the values in `pos`.

```
my_pos = {}
for key in pos.keys():
     x,y = pos[key]
     my_pos[key] = (-x,-y)#or whatever function you want
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos=my_pos, with_labels=False, node_size = 10)
```